# How to set header and footer for any drupal_mail messsage?

Tags: theming, emails

I am working with drupal 7 site.

I would like to know how to create email template for any email sent from drupal system?

Is there any hook or template should I implement in my custom module or override to make it beautiful like any newsletter emails are received.

I want following emails should be theming.

1. User Activation User
2. Password reset
3. Comment Notification etc...

Email template should looks like

```
<header>
Dear <User>
<Message Body goes here>
Thanks
<footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7).  All emails from the system "should" go through that.  You can alter the $message['body'] to add your header and footer.  If you only want to do this for certain emails, you can use an IF condition on the $key.

Edit: I think I pointed you to the wrong hook.  You probably want to use [hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to change every email that Drupal sends.

Comment: So, I can add override this `hook_mail` from my module will helpful.

e.g. `mymodule_mail(){
  // to do
}`

Comment: Yep, that should do it.  you can also take a look at the examples module. It has an example of that hook.  http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/email_example/email_example.module

Comment: I will try and let you know if there any issue. Thankx

Comment: I updated my original answer... I think you want to use hook_mail_alter to add a header/footer to every email that the system generates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [htmlmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module. which allow you to create template for your email and allow you theme your mail with [Echo](http://drupal.org/project/echo) module. Even you can add your logo, header, footer and any other information with echo module. See detail on these two project's page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom module or willing to do some custom code then please follow this link 
[How to use drupal_mail() to send emails with custom template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/how-to-use-drupal-mail-to-send-emails-with-custom-template/55197#55197)

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let me check that link

Comment: I would like to know that, `HOOK_MAIL()` hook create using `mymodule_mail()` always route through my module hook for mail for any mail send from whole system?

e.g. commerce module send emails also route from `mymodule_mail()` to theming body or ONLY System mail can route from `mymodule_mail()`.

Comment: I didn't get what you asked in the comment but just to let you know, every time a drupal_mail is called every HOOKs associated with hook_mail is invoked. So the mail object gets all the values from all the invoking functions.

Comment: Yes, that was I asked.