# Do I need to use drupal_mail after the hook_form_contact_site_form_alter?

Tags: 7, emails

I have added on field in my site wide contact form through this code :

```
    function cstm_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    // Add a phone number field to the contact form.
    $form['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#title' => t('Your phone'),
    );

    // Define the order of the top level elements on the form (include those from contact_site_form().
    $order = array('name', 'mail', 'phone', 'subject', 'cid', 'message', 'copy', 'actions');

    // Order the elements by changing their #weight property.
    foreach($order as $key => $field) {
    $form[$field]['#weight'] = $key;
    }
    }
```

Now Do I need to add `drupal_mail` with phone number into it or **Drupal** will consider it automatically ? As I am new to drupal I don't know much about it.

Comment: You have modified the form builder, which is only the first part. Now, you need to see how the module sends the email and build its body.

Comment: So basically I need to use `drupal_mail` ? Can I append my phone number in Body part of message like this `$message['body'][] = t('Phone') .': '. $message['params']['phone'];` ?
Is it good practice to do in this way ?

Comment: hook_mail_alter is what you need, because you are altering email sent by another module. However, mail and form functions are not tied well and your first step would be to check if the form's submit handlers include all the responses at all. I understand what you are trying to do, and I wish I could check the contact module for you. I'll try to post a contextual answer some time later as I'm just checking the answers until I get my dinner ready at the restaurant :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Waiting for your contextual answer.

Comment: Can I use that function in my theme's template file like function mythemename_contact_site_form_alter() ?

Comment: You need to double check that, but normally yes: most `alter` hooks can also be implemented by themes.

Comment: Best way to check is to install the Devel module, and put a call to `dpm($message)` in your `mytheme_mail_alter ()` function. You then submit the contact form as User-1 and you will see the contents of `$message`. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7).

`hook_mail_alter()` allows you to modify the email cleanly before it is sent. The Contact module passes the entire form state to `drupal_mail()`, so you have access to it in this alter hook via the `params` key.

A quick example. I haven't tested it:

```
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {
    $phone = $message['params']['phone'];

    $message['body'][] = "Phone number: " . check_plain($phone);
  }
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Oops, Ayesh K was faster than me :-). His answer is in the comments.

Comment: Will it be okay if I use `check_plain` ?

Comment: Actually, if you don't use an HTML email module, you can even just append it. Drupal sends emails in plain text by default, so there's no security issue there. Or, even better would be `t("Phone: @num", array('@num' => $phone))`. That way, it's translatable and safe.

Comment: Can I use that function in my theme's template file like function `mythemename_contact_site_form_alter()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is already answered [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/55197/26318)

Also if you are looking for basic tutorial you can check below links

http://www.blog.yamandi.com/how-use-drupalmail-function-tutorial

http://www.chrisfree.me/2010/01/override-drupal-contact-form

http://www.panda-os.com/2013/02/drupal-email-system/#.VD5-TPmSxws

And If you want to theme the outgoing mails with the help of custom templates, you should use the [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module.

> Lets you theme your messages the same way you theme the rest of your website.

It works well with other modules, like [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print), [Mail mime](http://drupal.org/project/mailmime), etc.

You have to install the [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module in order to use HTML mail.