# How can I add a custom part to emails

Tags: 7, emails

How can I add create a multi-part email in D7?  I need to add custom part to an email.

I am trying to use hook_mail_alter to append a new content type.  The content type is Content-Type: text/calendar.  I can't figure out where to add it in the $message array.

I have tried mimemail but it seems to disregard my SMTP settings.

Comment: What do you mean by adding part to emails? Which email? User confirmation email, lost password email etc?

Comment: I do agree with @herci , without enough information provided in question , its impossible to answer .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to alter the email message before sending it out. you could change or alter the email body, sender, attachments....etc as you wish

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do.  hook_mail_alter gives me access to the message array.  But I don't see how I can add another content type to the message.

Comment: What you mean "add another content type to the message."?

Comment: Emails are composed of different content types: Content-Type: text/plain, Content-Type: text/html, etc. I need add another content type of Content-Type: text/calendar;

Comment: I see, it's a bit confusing becase I thought you are refering to "Drupal content types". anyway according to the API you can change that in the "$headers" param

Comment: Any examples anywhere?

Comment: something similar here [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/55197/16315) `$headers = array(
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; format=flowed',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
        'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal',
    );`